# IP Address validation for usable range

Tags: regex, validation, ip

I'm using the following regex test to validate IP Addresses and it does appear to be working.

`/\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b/`

However I've been advised off the following

> highest value for 1st octet is 223 (224-239 being Multicast, 240 and higher are reserved) highest value for 4th octet is 254

How do I adjust the regex to match this criteria ?

I've tried setting the first part `25[0-5]` to `22[0-3]|` but that still allowed an address with 224.x.x.x

Could someone advise how to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you _have_ to use a regex for this?!

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried setting the first part `25[0-5]` to `22[0-3]|`

You also need to adjust the second part, changing `[0-4]` to `[01]`

I suppose you didn't have an issue with the 4th octet where `[0-5]` should become `[0-4]`

Comment: @Tom, was this not the answer you were looking for? Maybe I misunderstood the question.